# Star Trek Next Gen/DS9 crossovers?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9

How many times does the Next Gen storyline cross over with that of DS9? And how significant are those crossovers to either storyline, if any?

Comment: Do you mean during the time both aired, or crossovers throughout DS9's run? Also, how big - does just the appearance of a character from TNG count?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The biggest storyline crossover that isn't character-specific is probably the [Maquis](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Maquis):

- The first hints that something bad might come up later was in **TNG** 4x12, [The Wounded](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Wounded_(episode)), where we learn that the Cardassians had in the past sought to expand into Federation space, and relations along the border are still tense.
- Federation colonists were permitted to continue living in their colonies under Cardassian jurisdiction in **TNG** 7x20, [Journey's End](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Journey's_End_(episode)).
- The Maquis formed in **DS9** 2x20/21, [The Maquis, Part I](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Maquis,_Part_I_(episode)) and [Part II](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Maquis,_Part_II_(episode)) to deal with Cardassian subterfuge that the Federation was not (or could not legally) deal with.
- The Maquis eventually grew strong enough to outright attack the Cardassians, such as in **TNG** 7x24, [Preemptive Strike](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Preemptive_Strike_(episode)).

  - This is also the final appearance of [Ro Laren](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Ro_Laren), a Bajoran who writers wanted to move over to Deep Space Nine.  When the actress declined the role, the character was modified and replaced with [Kira Nerys](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Kira_Nerys).
- [Thomas Riker](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Thomas_Riker) joins the Maquis at some point between his creation in **TNG** 6x24, [Second Chances](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Second_Chances_(episode)) and appearance in **DS9** 3x09, [Defiant](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Defiant_(episode)).
- [One Maquis cell](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Maquis#Chakotay.27s_cell_and_the_USS_Voyager) ended up in the Delta Quadrant and joined with the USS Voyager to get back home.
- The Maquis made various additional appearances in DS9 before their destruction in **DS9** 5x15, [By Inferno's Light](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/By_Inferno's_Light_(episode)).  Only a few isolated cells remained, which were for the most part captured and imprisoned.

---

Another that's less "story arc" and more "background" is the Cardassian Occupation of Bajor in general.  We're first introduced to it through Ro Laren in TNG 5x03, [Ensign Ro](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Ensign_Ro_(episode)), where we learn that Cardassia annexed Bajor 40 years prior, and the Bajorans have since resorted to terrorism to regain their freedom.  Come DS9, that freedom has been won and Kira Nerys was rather proud of being one of those terrorists/freedom fighters.

DS9 was set up so that all of this background is reintroduced early on, hence why it's not so much a story arc.

Comment: Despite my phrasing on the comment on KyleJones's answer, this was all that came to mind for larger arcs (instead of singular characters) once I actually skimmed the episode titles

Comment: Both of y'all forgot the TNG episode(s?) where Bashir worked with Data and La Forge on the Enterprise.  They worked on some artifact from the Gamma Quadrant, and yadda yadda yadda, Data gains the ability to dream.

Comment: @Keen Yes, I mentioned it in the comment on Kyle's answer.  I consider that more of a character crossover than anything arc/storyline-related, which is why I left it out, along with all the other characters who simply appeared in both

Answer (score 15):

### *Deep Space Nine* episodes with *The Next Generation* characters:

- [S01E01 "Emissary"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Emissary_(episode)) - recap of Borg battle at Wolf 359 which occurred in TNG's "Best of Both Worlds", Picard, O'Brien from NCC-1701D.
- [S01E02 "Past Prologue"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Past_Prologue_(episode)) - Lursa and B'Etor from the House of Duras, introduced in TNG's "Redemption" return.  Also Keiko O'Brien makes her first appearance on DS9 having been introduced in TNG's "In Theory".
- [S1E06 "Q-Less"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Q-Less_(episode)) - Vash, introduced in TNG's "Captain's Holiday" and Q, introduced in TNG's "Encounter at Farpoint" return.
- [S1E17 "The Forsaken"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Forsaken_(episode)) - Lwaxana Troi, introduced in TNG's "Haven" returns.  Also in [S03E10 "Fascination"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Fascination_(episode)) and [S04E21 "The Muse"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Muse_(episode)).
- [S03E01 "The Search (part 1)"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Search,_Part_I_(episode)) - Admiral Nechayev, introduced in TNG's "Chain of Command" returns.  Also in [S03E02 "The Search (part 2)"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Search,_Part_II_(episode)).
- [S03E09 "Defiant"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Defiant_(episode)) - Thomas Riker, introduced in TNG's "Second Chances" returns.
- [S04E01 "The Way Of The Warrior"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Way_of_the_Warrior_(episode)) - Worf from TNG returns and remains until the end of the series.
- [S04E15 "Sons Of Mogh"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sons_of_Mogh_(episode)) - Kurn, introduced in TNG's "Sins of the Father" returns.
- [S05E01 "Apocalypse Rising"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Apocalypse_Rising_(episode)) - Gowron, introduced in TNG's "Reunion" returns.
- [S06E03 "Sons and Daughters"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sons_and_Daughters_(episode)) - Alexander Rozhenko, introduced in TNG's "Reunion" as Worf's son, returns as a young adult.

### *The Next Generation* episodes with *Deep Space Nine* characters:

- [S06E16 "Birthright (part 1)"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Birthright,_Part_I_(episode)) - Bashir interacts with Data and Geordi on *Enterprise* while Crusher and Picard visit DS9.
- [S07E21 "First Born"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Firstborn_(episode)) - Riker has Worf contact Quark on DS9.

Comment: So I started on arc crossovers (what limited there are); if you want to fill out characters, there's also Q, Vash, and Bashir

Comment: Both of y'all forgot the TNG episode(s?) where Bashir worked with Data and La Forge on the Enterprise.  They worked on some artifact from the Gamma Quadrant, and yadda yadda yadda, Data gains the ability to dream.

Comment: Yah, I forgot a few episodes; will update answer today.

Comment: @Keen - That was **"Birthright (part 1)"**

Comment: There's also Worf's son Alexander Rozhenko (different actor but same character), Kurn (his bio brother), as well as his adoptive parents. And Chancellor Gowron. And of course Chief and Keiko O'Brien, and their daughter. All are originally TNG characters.

Comment: 'Admiral Nechayev, introduced in TNG's "Chain of Command" returns' — or _DOES SHE?!?!?_ (Actually yeah she does I think.)